# Let $D_{2n}$ be the dihedral group of order $2n$. Let $H$ be the set of rotations of the regular $n$-gon. Is $H\lhd D_{2n}$?

Tags: group-theory, dihedral-groups

Let $D_{2n}$ be the dihedral group of order $2n$, *i.e.*, the group of symmetries of the regular $n$-gon.

Let $H$ be the set of rotations of the regular $n$-gon.

Is  $H\lhd D_{2n}$?

Comment: Do you know the definition of "normal subgroup"? Which attempts have you made to apply this definition to the situation on hand?

Comment: You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: A normal subgroup is a subgroup that is invariant under conjugation by any element of the original group. So for example H would be a normal subgroup iff gHg^(-1)  = H for any g an element of G.@HenningMakholm

Comment: Which attempts have you made to apply this definition to the situation at hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is. Moreover, the dihedral group happens to be a semidirect product of the subgroup of rotations of regular $n$-gon and a subgroup, generated by a mirror symmetry. You can find more about semidirect products here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidirect_product